# Upload image in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, file-upload, cakephp-2.0

I simply want to have in my function (add) the file upload process in my cake application. i have tried various tutorial across the web bur I could reach the solution to my problem. I am new to cake and I dont want to reinvent the wheel I just want to learn based on what I have implemented so far. I am truly grateful for your help.

add.ctp

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Movie'); ?>
    <?php echo __('Add Movie'); ?>
    <?php
    echo $this->Form->hidden('movie_id');
    echo $this->Form->input('title');
    echo $this->Form->input('date', array(
        'type'  => 'date',
        'label' => 'Date',
        'empty' => false,
        'dateFormat' => 'DMY',
        'minYear'=>'1990',
        'maxYear'=>date('Y'),
       ));
    echo $this->Form->input('description');
    echo $this->Form->input('file', array('type' => 'file'));?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
```

THE CONTROLLER

```
 public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $this->Movie->create();
        }
     if ($this->Movie->save($this->request->data))
        {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The movie has been created'));
        $this->redirect (array('action'=>'index'));
        }
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? There are many plugin for image / file uploading for CakePHP.

You can also write your own PHP code to process the upload.

Answer (score 0):

**Table structure for table `movies`**

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `movies` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `movie_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `file` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   UNIQUE KEY `movie_id` (`movie_id`),
   KEY `id` (`id`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

**Create Model located at /app/Model/Movies.php**

```
  <?php
  class Movie extends AppModel {

  }
  ?>
```

Create Controller in app/Controller/Movies.php

```
<?php 
class MoviesController extends AppController {
    public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $maxId = $this->Movie->find('first', array(
            'order' => 'movie_id DESC',
            'fields' => array('Movie.movie_id')
        ));
        $maxId = (isset($maxId['Movie']['movie_id'])? $maxId['Movie']['movie_id'] : 0);
        $this->request->data['Movie']['movie_id'] = $maxId+1;

        $folderToSaveFiles = WWW_ROOT . 'img/uploads/' ;

        if(!empty($this->request->data['Movie']['file']))
        {
            $file = $this->request->data['Movie']['file'];
            $ext = substr(strtolower(strrchr($file['name'], '.')), 1);
            $arr_ext = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif','png');
            if(in_array($ext, $arr_ext))
            {
                $newFilename = $this->request->data['Movie']['title'].'.'.$ext;                 
                $result = move_uploaded_file( $file['tmp_name'], $folderToSaveFiles . $newFilename );
                $this->request->data['Movie']['file'] = $newFilename;
                $this->Movie->save($this->request->data);
                //debug($this->request->data);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Note** : Create a directory in app/webroot/img/uploads/ & upload directory must be write permission.

Comment: thanks for your answer my friend however I used this script and it worked as well but I wanted the images to be called from the database as I want the images to be displayed as a column of each post in my index.ctp

Comment: you want to save image name into table??

Comment: Yes I managed to save the image in the database but displaying the recor was only giving me the image name not the actual image.

Comment: So, first add a field in your form, before save you should be rename the uploaded file.

Comment: I have changed my answer, please check.

Comment: sorry for the late reply @u2460470. i tried this solution however i got this error=> Illegal string offset 'name' [APP\Controller\MoviesController.php

Comment: Andrew, Where you getting this error & mention this error. I think, something you missing. This code work properly in my default cake.

Comment: hey @u2460470 which is the version of cake u use? Apart from that I had set the solution step by step really carefully and I still get the error Illegal string offset 'name'[APP\Controller\MoviesController.php, line ..] and it doesnt pass any data to the database

Comment: I also use cake2. would u be able to email me a zip file of the working code please? if so my email address is l_papadjiakos@hotmail.com thanks a lot